# Couldn't able to establish SSIS connection manager with Citrix home page's Visual studio but able to execute SSRS report with run option

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, visual-studio-2013, citrix

We have Visual studio application in Citrix home page which is not able to establish SSIS connection manager, but it is able to execute SSRS report with run option and an error preventing SSRS preview from loading.

Error text:
**Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. Client unable to establish connection Encryption not supported on the client.**

Provider used in SSRS connection : .Net framework data provider for SQL server
Provider used in SSIS connection : Native OLE DB/SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Please let me know if any more details required.

Comment: Could you please provide the error that you get in SSIS?

Comment: Hi @MarkWojciechowicz,

Thanks for the reply.

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
Client unable to establish connection
Encryption not supported on the client.

Comment: How are you executing the package and is the connection manager configured with parameters for the server or connection string?

Comment: It is through connection string